# Why isn't Drupal aggregator configurable?

Tags: feeds

I am trying to display the RSS feed of this page: http://groups.yahoo.com/group/actventurers/, on a drupal website.

I have the aggregator module enabled, but when I go to `/admin/config/services`, only RSS Publishing is available.

Any ideas as to why it won't allow me to add any feeds?

Comment: I've never used aggregator, so I want to reverse the question. Why do you expect aggregator to be configurable?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds), it's import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds to Drupal.

Comment: Same problem with this module, it doesn't show up in /admin/stucture.  The modules are enabled, and I have checked permissions.

Comment: Enable Feeds UI, then visit http://YOUSITE.COM/admin/structure/feeds. Importing Feeds located here: http://YOUSITE.COM/import .